# SDN relationship uniqueness

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

Is it possible to define a unique relation type between two nodes in SDN?

I want to have only one relation of this type between the start node and end node, something like:

```
@Unique
@RelationshipEntity(type="TYPE")
public class Relation {

    @StartNode
    private NodeTypeOne source;

    @EndNode
    private NodeTypeTwo target;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a use case for this? I assume that if you only want relationships of one type between two nodes you just don't implement any logic that creates other relationships. Before creating a relationship of this type you can check if it already exists.

Comment: Sorry, the wordng of the question was not clear. I want only one relation of this type.

Comment: Which version of SDN?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SDN 4, there's no @Unique annotation available, you have to manage this yourself in the application code. If you don't have properties on the relation, then you should use a simple @Relationship rather than a relationship entity.

The current behaviour of SDN 4 for relationships is:

> Spring Data Neo4j ensures by default that there is only one
>   relationship of a given type between any two given entities. The
>   exception to this rule is when a relationship is specified as either
>   OUTGOING or INCOMING between two entities of the same type. In this
>   case, it is possible to have two relationships of the given type
>   between the two entities, one relationship in either direction.

For relationship entities,

> Multiple relationship entities which have the same property values and
>   relate the same nodes are indistinguishable from each other and are
>   represented as a single relationship by SDN 4.

Still, your application should add sufficient checks for these and not rely on uniqueness management by SDN as future versions may enhance/change behavior.